# Open folder of selected message and select the message

Tags: vba, outlook

When searching for items in All Outlook Items, it shows the messages/items found. Part of the search result items include the folder the message resides in. I'm trying to open a new window of the parent folder where the item resides then highlight that message in the new window. The following code opens the folder, but I cannot figure out how to locate and select the item.

```
'Opens folder in new windows of current messages folder location
 Public Sub OpenFolderPath()
  Dim obj As Object
  Dim objOLApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim objExp As Outlook.Explorer
  Dim F As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim Msg$
  Dim SelMsg As MailItem
  Set obj = Application.ActiveWindow
  If TypeOf obj Is Outlook.Inspector Then
    Set obj = obj.CurrentItem
  Else
    Set obj = obj.Selection(1)
  End If
  Set F = obj.Parent
  Msg = "The path is: " & F.Name & vbCrLf
  Msg = Msg & "Switch to the folder?"
  If MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    Set objExp = Application.Explorers.Add(F, olFolderDisplayNormal)
    objExp.Activate
  End If
' The following does not work
  For Each SelMsg In objExp.CurrentFolder.Items
    If obj.EntryID = SelMsg.EntryID Then
        MsgBox SelMsg.EntryID
' What to put here to select the found item.
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's code that will work:

```
'Opens folder in new windows of current messages folder location
 Public Sub OpenFolderPath()
  Dim obj As Object
  Dim objOLApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim objExp As Outlook.Explorer
  Dim F As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim Msg$
  Dim SelMsg As MailItem
  Dim i as Long
  Set obj = Application.ActiveWindow
  If TypeOf obj Is Outlook.Inspector Then
    Set obj = obj.CurrentItem
  Else
    Set obj = obj.Selection(1)
  End If
  Set F = obj.Parent
  Msg = "The path is: " & F.Name & vbCrLf
  Msg = Msg & "Switch to the folder?"
  If MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    Set objExp = Application.Explorers.Add(F, olFolderDisplayNormal)
    objExp.Activate
  End If

  'Wait for the user interface to catch up 
  '  (Wait for the new window to finish displaying)
  DoEvents 

  objExp.ClearSelection
  For Each SelMsg In objExp.CurrentFolder.Items
    If obj.EntryID = SelMsg.EntryID Then
        objExp.AddToSelection SelMsg
    End If
  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: DoEvents did not slow my processing enough. I had to interrupt with a MsgBox "Click Ok" immediately after DoEvents.

Comment: Thanks niton.  Instead of DoEvents, an earlier version of my code looped until the error condition cleared.  I took that loop out because I'm not a fan of code that relies on error conditions when everything is operating as expected.   In this case that might be the only way to do it (besides a user prompt).  At some point I'll revise this to find multiple files, open multiple windows (if they happen to be in different folders) and select each of them in the new windows.  That won't be hard from this point, but this will have to do for now.

Comment: If you wish to notify non-owners of a post, precede the username with @. I assumed the code worked for you but if not, seems better to put in klunky code that works rather than pretty, non-working code.

Answer (score -1):

```
'Opens folder in new windows of current messages folder location
 Public Sub OpenFolderPath()
  Dim obj As Object
  Dim objOLApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim objExp As Outlook.Explorer
  Dim F As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim Msg$
  Dim SelMsg As MailItem
  Dim i as Long
  Set obj = Application.ActiveWindow
  If TypeOf obj Is Outlook.Inspector Then
    Set obj = obj.CurrentItem
  Else
    Set obj = obj.Selection(1)
  End If
  Set F = obj.Parent
  Msg = "The path is: " & F.Name & vbCrLf
  Msg = Msg & "Switch to the folder?"
  If MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    Set objExp = Application.Explorers.Add(F, olFolderDisplayNormal)
    objExp.Activate
  End If
' The following does not work
  i = 1
  For Each SelMsg In objExp.CurrentFolder.Items
    If obj.EntryID = SelMsg.EntryID Then
        MsgBox objExp.CurrentFolder.Items.Item(i)
' What to put here to select the found item.
    End If
    i = i + 1
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Please explain what the changes in the answer are and how the address the OPs concern so I dont have to stare at it to see what is different.

Comment: Changes include adding new variable i, initialize i = 1, i = i + 1 and objExp.CurrentFolder.Items.Item(i) when both obj.EntryID match to SelMsg.EntryID.

Comment: This is close. I changed the if statement to     `If Not SelMsg Is Nothing And obj.EntryID = SelMsg.EntryID Then` because I was getting an error during the loop. So it finds the message but doesn't select it in the window. I also added `         Application.ActiveExplorer = objExp.CurrentFolder.Items.Item(i)
` after the msgbox, but that doesn't do it either.