# Select item after selecting parent folder

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to select a mail item within it's parent folder. I am using Outlook 2016.

The macro does the following:

- Gets the selected mail item in the explorer
- Selects it's parent folder
- Selects the mail item within the folder

The code works in debug mode but not at runtime. I guess that at runtime the explorer takes some time before being open.

I tried to wait for the explorer using the Sleep() method.

```
Public Sub SelectSelectedItemInParentFolder()    

    Dim outlook As Object
    Dim x As Long
    Dim strCats As String
    Dim arrSelection As Object
    Set outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set arrSelection = GetCurrentSelection
    Dim folder As outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim mail As outlook.MailItem

    If arrSelection.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox ("Nothing selected")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If arrSelection.item(1).Class = OlObjectClass.olMail Then

        Set mail = arrSelection.item(1)

    End If

    Set folder = arrSelection.item(1).Parent

    If Not (folder Is Nothing) Then

        ' this works fine at runtime, the folder is selected
        Set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = folder

        ' below code works fine only in debug mode, when steping into the code.
        ' At runtime, it seems that the explorer is not yet loaded when the code runs       
        If Not (mail Is Nothing) Then

            For x = 1 To folder.Items.Count

                If folder.Items(x).Class = OlObjectClass.olMail Then

                    If folder.Items(x).EntryID = mail.EntryID Then

                        Application.ActiveExplorer.ClearSelection
                        Application.ActiveExplorer.AddToSelection (folder.Items(x))
                        x = folder.Items.Count

                    End If

                End If

            Next x

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What is it you want to do with selected item?

Comment: It is sometimes impossible to figure out how to slow the process in the same way the debugger does. This https://stackoverflow.com/a/52023490/1571407 describes three possible options DoEvents, DoEvents and Msgbox and looping until an error condition clears. If you find an answer remember to post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you ever want to loop through *all* items in a folder? If you know the item's entry id, simply open it using `Namespace.GetItemFromID`, read its parent's entry id (`MailItem.Parent.EntryID` property), then compare it with the entry id of the folder in question using `Namespace.ComparerEntryIDs`. If they match, just add the item to the selection.

Comment: Actually it's because my item results from a search. What I want to do is to search for an item using search box, if found then select the item using my mouse and then call the macro to open the item's parent folder and finally select the item within the parent's folder. It's that final action that I am not able to do.

Comment: But that is not what your code is doing. What are you searching for?